# 'vector' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, stdvector

I apologize for asking a question that should have a simple solution, but it's driving me nuts. I've checked for all the common errors: namespace std, spelling, include vector, etc. Below is the abbreviated code for my video.h file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <new>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Video
{
    public:
        Video(string, string, string, float, int);
        vector<Video*> video_ptrs;
        void print();
};
```

And here is the code for my main.cpp

```
#include "video.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ...

    Video* temp_here = new Video(title, url, comment, length, rating);
    video_ptrs.push_back(temp_here);

return 0;
}
```

The error that returns says, "'video_ptrs' was not declared in this scope." Thank you ahead of time for any help given.

Comment: You meant to write something like `temp_here->video_ptrs.push_back(temp_here);`?

Comment: You've placed a list of videos inside of the video object itself.  This means that each video will have a list of videos.  If that is not what you intended, you should either move the list outside of the class or make it a [static member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) so that there is only one list common to all Video.  Also, you should always be sure your program runs as many `delete`s as it does `new`s, or look up "smart pointers" for taking care of the `delete`s for you.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Sorry about the noob question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`video_ptrs` is a member of `Video`, call it with the object you just created:

```
Video* temp_here = new Video(title, url, comment, length, rating);
temp_here->video_ptrs.push_back(temp_here);
```

This adds a pointer `temp_here` to the `vector` of that same object though, I'm not sure if this is intended.

Answer (score 0):

video_ptrs is indeed not declared in main. You shall use

```
temp_here->video_ptrs...
```